# Errors writing a dice simulator using randomisation in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, probability, dice

I'm making a dice simulator in python. The program throws four dices 1000 times, then calculates how many times the sum of the four dices is equal to 21 or higher. This is what I've written so far:

```
    import random

    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice4 = random.randint(1,6)

    sum = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4

    n = 0    # the amount of times the sum of the score was 21 or higher

    for i in range(1000):
        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
    
        for sum >= 21:
            n = n + 1

    print("You got 21 or higher", n, "times.")
```

However, the program's terminal only shows "You got 21 or higher 0 times." or "You got 21 or higher 1000 times." when I attempt to run it. How do I write the code so it calculates the amount of times the sum of the score is 21 or higher out of 1000 throws of the dice, as well as print the amount of times in the terminal? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you quite sure you wrote `for sum >= 21:`? This is not valid python syntax. That `for` should be an `if`. The other issue is that your forgot to update variable `sum` inside the `for`-loop, so it keeps its initial value (the sum of the four dice on the very first roll).

Comment: You are not updating sum inside the for loop, by the way avoid using this name as it shadows the built-in sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Can you try this

```
import random

n = 0   

for i in range(1000):
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
    sum = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4
    if sum >= 21:
        n = n + 1

print("You got 21 or higher", n, "times.")
```

Comment: Aaah, I see the sum definition in the for-loop is what I was missing... It runs perfectly now that I've added it, thank you Cenk! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should update variable `sum` inside the `for`-loop. Otherwise, it keeps its initial value, which is the sum of the four dice in the very first roll.

Note that their is a python builtin function called `sum`, and it is very bad practice to use builtin names for your variables. Below, I renamed the variable to `sumOfDice`.

```py
import random

n = 0    # the amount of times the sum of the score was 21 or higher

for i in range(1000):
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
    
    sumOfDice = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4
    
    if sumOfDice >= 21:
        n = n + 1

print("You got 21 or higher", n, "times.")
```

### Other improvements

When you start to have variables with numbers in their names, you should ask yourself: do I really need four named variables for the dice? Wouldn't it be easier to use one single list to hold the four values? If `dice` is a list, then you can access the individual values as `dice[0]`, `dice[1]`, etc. But you can also use loops list comprehensions and other cool python features to manipulate the list. You can even call the python builtin `sum` to get the sum of the list!!

```py
import random
n = 0
for i in range(1000):
    dice = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(4)]
    if sum(dice) >= 21:
        n = n + 1
print("You got 21 or higher, {} times.".format(n))
```

Comment: +1 for the list of N dice rolls. In this specific case, we could even write `rolls_sum = 4 * random.randint(1, 6)` because the average result will be the same.

Comment: @Guimoute That's wrong. We are not interested in the average result, we are counting the number of times the result is above 21. Imagine if I flip a coin with "0" on one side and "10" on the other, and ask you "how many times is the value greater than 7?" The average of 0 and 10 is 5, and 5 is never above 7. Yet the correct answer should be about half the number of flips.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for your input and the tip on efficient python features Stef! I feel like implementing aforementioned features might be a little over-kill for me right now, as I've just begun with coding in Python, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for future endeavours when I'm a little more comfortable using the language! :-)

Comment: @quasireal Even if you're a beginner I still recommend using `dice = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(4)]; sumOfDice = dice[0] + dice[1] + dice[2] + dice[3]` rather than the very repetitive `dice1 = random.randint(1,6); dice2 = random.randint(1,6); dice3 = random.randint(1,6); dice4 = random.randint(1,6); sumOfDice = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the sum of dice within the for loop.

In your example, sum always equals to the sum of random numbers generated in first 4 calls to `random.randint`, but you should recalculate the sum each time.

Also, in line where you have `for sum >= 21`, the `for` should be replaced with an `if`. `for` is used for repetition, `if` for conditional execution.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to define the dices, each `random.randint(1,6)` is a dice itself.

```
import random

n = 0    # the amount of times the sum of the score was 21 or higher

for i in range(1000):
    sum = random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)

    if sum >= 21:
        n = n+1

print("You got 21 or higher", str(n), "times.")
```

**Here's a pythonic way:**

```
dice_sum = [int((x/x)) for x in range(1,1001) if  random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) >= 21]

print("You got 21 or higher", str(sum(dice_sum)), "times.")
```

All I'm doing is getting the index each time the dice is `>= 21`, then dividing it by the same index so it returns 1 to the list, I then get the sum of list, which is just how many times 1 has been added to the list, which is how many times the dice was `>= 21`.